# C switch returns default inside if/else

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, return, default

I have the following problem: i have two `switch` statements. They work perfectly when separated, but the minute I put both of them into an `if`/`else`. `switch` always returns the default(error). I am sorry for the difficult wording, now I have copied in the whole program so you can check it, I have tried what you said, but it didn't seem to help. So for an example, when it asks for the number, my input is `2`. Then it asks for what character do I want to choose (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`), and no matter which I write in, it gives me the default output like I have type a wrong character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void tomb_beolvas(int *szamok);
void tomb_kiir(int *szamok);
void tomb_sorrend(int *szamok);
void sorrend_kiir(int *szamok);
void kalkulator(int *szamok);

int main() {
    int szamok[10];
    tomb_beolvas(szamok);
    tomb_kiir(szamok);
    tomb_sorrend(szamok);
    sorrend_kiir(szamok);
    kalkulator(szamok);
    return 0;
}

void tomb_beolvas(int *szamok) {
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        szamok[i] = rand() % (10) + 1;
    }
    return;
}

void tomb_kiir(int *szamok) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", szamok[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void tomb_sorrend(int *szamok) {
    int i;
    int a, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {
            if (szamok[i] > szamok[j]) {
                a =  szamok[i];
                szamok[i] = szamok[j];
                szamok[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void sorrend_kiir(int *szamok) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n%d", szamok[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void kalkulator(int *szamok) {
    char jel;
    int a, b, donto;
    printf("\nKerem valassza ki milyen modon szeretne megadni az adatokat:\n"
           " 1.: egyben(peldaul 5. + 8.)\n"
           " 2.: kulon(peldaul + aztan 5. es 8.)\n");
    scanf("%d", &donto);
    if (donto == 1) {
        printf("\nKerem irja be hanyadik szamokat szeretne es koze hogy milyen kalkulaciot szeretne vegezni(pl.: 5 + 8):\n");
        while (scanf("%d %c %d", &a, &jel, &b)) {
            switch (jel) {
              case '+':
                printf("%d", szamok[a-1] + szamok[b-1]);
                break;

              case '-':
                printf("%d", szamok[a-1] - szamok[b-1]);
                break;

              case '*':
                printf("%d", szamok[a-1] * szamok[b-1]);
                break;

              case '/':
                printf("%d", szamok[a-1] / szamok[b-1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else
    if (donto == 2) {
        printf("Adj meg egy jelet (+, -, *, /): ");
        scanf("%c", &jel);

        printf("add meg hanyadik szamokkal akarsz szamolni: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

        switch (jel) {
          case '+':
            printf("%d + %d = %d", szamok[a], szamok[b], szamok[a] + szamok[b]);
            break;

          case '-':
            printf("%d - %d = %d", szamok[a], szamok[b], szamok[a] - szamok[b]);
            break;

          case '*':
            printf("%d * %d = %d", szamok[a], szamok[b], szamok[a] * szamok[b]);
            break;

          case '/':
            printf("%d / %d = %d", szamok[a], szamok[b], szamok[a] / szamok[b]);
            break;

          // operator doesn't match any case constant +, -, *, /
          default:
            printf("Error! operator is not correct");
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `int szamok[]={};` is not valid C.

Comment: This code does not match your description.

Comment: Your example input (in the prompt for `donto`) has periods after each number, but you scan integers. If your actual input is like that, the operator will be the dot and the second number may not have been read. `scanf` has a return value. Check it.

Comment: Your program would be easier for other people to understand if you provided a [mre] in English language, i.e. with English output and variable names.

Comment: Where is the `if/else`? I can only see an `if`. Where is the `default` for your `switch` You provided some code that is not related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your problem is a classic `scanf()` issue: instead of `scanf("%c", &jel);` you should use

```
scanf(" %c", &jel);  // notice the initial space before the `%c`
```

This skips the newline left pending after the `scanf("%d", &donto);`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your switch statements, however:

```
int szamok[]={};
```

You can't make an empty array, you should declare it with a size:

```
const int size = 10;
int szamok[10];
```

From what I can tell, you invoked undefined behavior by accessing `szamok` with an out of bounds index (which is any positive number, as you got an empty array).